# QTreeView doesn't scale - is there a workaround to fetch fewer ModelIndexes?

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I'm working on an app that uses Qt's `QTreeView` to display hierarchical data.  In some cases a single leaf in the hierarchy will contain 100,000's of child nodes.

I've discovered that `QTreeView` can't handle too many child nodes.

This is because when the user opens a parent node, Qt fetches ALL of the child nodes' `ModelIndexes`, not just the ones that are needed to fill the `QTreeView` display.

Why does it do this, and is there any workaround to make it fetch fewer `ModelIndexes`?

Comment: Have you set the view to use uniform row heights?

Comment: What you mean by "can't handle". I'm working with treeviews with 1KK+ items and everything is OK. But we are using custom, performance optimized models :)

Comment: By "can't handle," I mean that QT uses up all my memory and crashes.  It tries to fetch ALL of the child nodes' ModelIndexes, not just the ones needed to fill the display

Comment: What model do you use? If you run out of memory - then problem is in your model, not in view.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was unfortunately useless due to QTreeWidget(I am using QTreeWidget to simplyfy) sliders cannot be set by user.
Your goal could be achieved by using extra QScrollBar.

MainWidget.h

```
class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    QTreeWidget* Tree;
    QScrollBar* Bar;
private slots:
    void tree(QTreeWidgetItem*);
    void slider();
};
```

MainWidget.cpp

```
MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent) {
    Tree = new QTreeWidget();
    Tree->header()->hide();
    connect(Tree,SIGNAL(itemExpanded(QTreeWidgetItem*)),this,SLOT(tree(QTreeWidgetItem*)));
    Bar = new QScrollBar(Qt::Vertical);
    Bar->setRange(0,100000);
    connect(Bar,SIGNAL(sliderReleased()),this,SLOT(slider()));
    for(uint i=0;i<10;i++) {
        QTreeWidgetItem* Item=new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList()<<QString::number(i)); //Add 10 topLevelItems
        Tree->addTopLevelItem(Item);
        for(uint j=0;j<30;j++) {
            Item->addChild(new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList()<<QString::number(j))); //Add first 30 items
        }
    }
    QHBoxLayout* Lay = new QHBoxLayout();
    Lay->addWidget(Tree);
    Lay->addWidget(Bar);
    setLayout(Lay);
}
void MainWidget::tree(QTreeWidgetItem* I) { //SLOT Only one item expanded
    Tree->blockSignals(true); //Block SIGNAL(itemExpanded())
    Tree->collapseAll();
    Tree->expandItem(I);
    Tree->blockSignals(false);//Allow SIGNAL(itemExpanded())
}
void MainWidget::slider() { //SLOT manage tree
    for (int i=0;i<Tree->topLevelItemCount();i++) {
        if (Tree->topLevelItem(i)->isExpanded()) {
            for(uint j=Tree->topLevelItem(i)->childCount(); j>0;j--) { //Clear children
                delete Tree->topLevelItem(i)->child(j-1);
            }
            uint Value = Bar->value();
            for(uint j=0; j<30; j++) {
                Tree->topLevelItem(i)->addChild(new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList()<<QString::number(Value+j))); //Add 30 new children
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you have one slider to scroll the QTreeWidget and the second one to change content of expanded topLevelItem.